# WKWebview is nil even though it is hooked to storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `WKWebview` that is if course hooked up to the file through storyboard. You can see it is hooked in this picture:

[image]

[image]

As you see both in storyboard and in the `UIViewController` file, the `webView` is hooked.

I get a nil from the `webView`the first time I call it in the `viewDidLoad`on line 36.

[image]

This is the error:
`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

How can I get Xcode to recognize there is a web view??

**EDIT**
I load the VC like this:

```
let vc = joinFromInAppViewController()
vc.purchaseDate = purchaseDate
vc.purchaseEndDate = purchaseEndDate
vc.membershipPurchased = membershipPurchased
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The ViewController where the webView is in:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import RevealingSplashView
import SwiftEntryKit

class joinFromInAppViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    var purchaseDate: Int = 0
    var purchaseEndDate: Int = 0
    var membershipPurchased: String = ""
    
    let revealingSplash = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RevealingSplashIconImage"), iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: 125, height: 125), backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 225/255, green: 32/255, blue: 62/255, alpha: 1.0))
        
    var attributesShow = EKAttributes.bottomFloat
        
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(revealingSplash)
        revealingSplash.animationType = SplashAnimationType.heartBeat
        
        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(myRequest)
        
        //revealingSplash.startAnimation()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you load the vc ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan just added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an id to the vc inside storyboard and load it like this

```
let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Id") as! IoinFromInAppViewController
```

Comment: That worked! Why did that work and not the thing I was doing?

Comment: This line `let vc = joinFromInAppViewController()` loads the code only and not the vc layout from storyboard